# Prove that there exist one subsequence s.t. $\forall \;0\le a<b\le 1$, $\lim_{ k\to \infty} \int_ a^b f_{n_k }(t)dt$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, integration

Problem: Let $(f_n)$ be a uniformly bounded sequence of real valued continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Prove that there is ONE subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ such that for every  $0\le a < b \le 1$, we have $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \int_a^b \! f_{n_k}(t) dt $$ exists.

Context: Advanced Undergraduate Analysis. Familiar with Real Analysis by Carothers and Principles of Analysis by Rudin

I think it would be obvious to show this for all rationals inbetween a and b but I do not know how to start showing that there is a single subsequence.
Any help would be appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: I doubt there would be only one. It was most probably meant '**at least one**'. Any subsequence of such a sequence will be suitable, too.

Comment: Hint: To prove it for rationals $a,b$ use a diagonal argument.

Comment: Thank for the replies, I was of the impression it was 'at least one' but 'ONE' was emphasized so I'm still confused as to what it meant. Also, Jose could you expand a bit on the application of a diagonal argument in this particular case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Apply [Arzelà–Ascoli theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem) to the sequence $\int_0^xf_n(t)dt$, $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was able to prove that there exist a subsequence of $F_n = \int_0^x f_n(t)dt$ that converges uniformly for all $x \in  [0,1]$.

Comment: My question is that since this is true then for $ a < b \in [0,1] \int_0^a f_n(t)dt$ and $\int_0^b f_n(t)dt$ have uniformly converging subsequences then we have that by subtraction $\int_a^b f_n(t)dt$ has a uniformly converging subsequence?

Comment: @jimmywho:  Since you have proved that there exists $n_k\to\infty$, such that $F_{n_k}(x)=\int_0^xf_{n_k}(t)d t$ uniformly converges to some $F$ on $[0,1]$, then by the definition of uniformly convergence, $\int_a^b f_{n_k}(t)d t=F_{n_k}(b)-F_{n_k}(a)$ uniformly converges to $F(b)-F(a)$.

Comment: Thanks, I believe that was what I was attempting to state in my comment. I believe that this is the result I was looking for but am I missing anything?

Comment: @jimmywho: Sorry, I cannot understand what you mean. Is there anything still unclear to you?

Comment: Sorry I got sidetrack thinking about my first idea of proving it for a,b rational, but I see that through the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem that it holds for all a,b in [0,1]. Thank you, you've been very helpful.

Comment: @jimmywho: You are welcome.